# Change the style of an element with css whose style has already been modified with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a "filter bar" that is displayed when the screen has a certain width, and it disappears when the screen is to narrow. I have implemented this in my code by using media queries and it works.

When the screen is narrow, a button shows up, to display the hidden bar. I have implemented this code in javascript, and when I click on it, the bar is displayed/hidden : it works.

Now, my problem is : when I display the hidden bar with the button (so the window is narrow), and I increase the size of the window until reaching a width for which the bar have to shows up, it doesn't. It seems like the javascript imposes the style of the bar, so that the media queries don't work. How to manage this ?

My code with the important elements is shown below :

```js
function displayHideFiltrerPar() {

    let tmp = document.getElementById('container-left-small-screen');

    if (tmp.style.display == "none" || tmp.style.display == "") {
        tmp.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
        tmp.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  
 .res-button-filtrer-par {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }

  #container-left-small-screen {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: -130px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  /* Size M  */
 .res-button-filtrer-par {
    display: none;
  }

  #container-left-small-screen {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="res-button-filtrer-par res-button" type="button" onClick="displayHideFiltrerPar();">
    <span>Display filter bar</span>
</button>

<div id="container-left-small-screen">
    Filter bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the button change the style directly, let it add and remove a class `hidden` instead. Then you can make your CSS depend not only on the media query, but also on that class, as demonstrated in this simplified example:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #btn {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
  }
  #container-left-small-screen:not(.hidden) {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #container-left-small-screen.hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #btn {
    display: none;
  }
  #container-left-small-screen {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('container-left-small-screen').classList.toggle('hidden')">
    Toggle filter bar
</button>

<div id="container-left-small-screen">Filter bar</div>
```

Instead of the [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method, you can use `add` to add a class or `remove` to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution ! However, I have an issue when I'm trying to implementing the solution in my code. The id of the bar is : "#container-left-small-screen" : and the code you provided to me doesn't work with this id. How to resolve it ?

Secondly : what is the syntax if I want to add/delete the class of all the element of a class ? .class.classList.toggle() ?